# Изменить поле бина через h:inputText JSF 2

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, xhtml

Есть xhtml-файл:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="userId" 
                     value="#{user.id}" 
                     valueChangeListener="#{user.changeId}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

И есть бин:

```
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

    private String id;

    public String getId() { return id;}

    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id;}

    public void changeId(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        id = event.getNewValue(); 
    }

}
```

Я ожидаю, что поле `id` моего бина будет изменяться при изменении поля `inputText`, но `valueChangeListener` не срабатывает. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

`valueChangeListener` не срабатывает т.к. не происходит сабмит значения из поля.
Для корректной работы можно использовать AJAX:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="userId" 
                 value="#{user.id}" 
                 valueChangeListener="#{user.changeId}">
        <a4j:ajax event="change" immediate="true" />
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

Но лучше вместо `event="change"` использовать `event="blur"`, таким образом значение будет сабмититься в бин при потере фокуса, а не при каждом изменении значения поля.

Comment: зачем использовать a4j если для этой задачи достаточно встроенного ajax? не знаю как с a4j, но в jsf ajax change срабатывает при потере фокуса если новое значение не соответствует старому.

Answer (score 0):

для `JSF2` более уместно использование слушателя на самом ajax событии, нежели aтавизм `JSF1.2` `valueChangeListener`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="userId" value="#{user.id}">
        <f:ajax event="change" render="@this" execute="@this" listener="#{user.changeId}"/>
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```